# how to create a form with a checkbox for each record for a model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    calories = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=ACTIVITY_TYPES, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomerActivity(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.activity.name
```

I want to create a form that allows the user to add an activity to their own list, thus making a CustomerActivity entry.  I am thinking the best way to do this is create a form with a check box for every Activity record and then when the form is published save a CustomerActivity.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need a CustomerActivity model?  I would just move "customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)" to the activity table

Comment: I have a list of activities that every user can choose from. Not every user will be associated to one.

Comment: Davko What Atma is coding is a ManyToMany relationship in django. I would use this instead, however with a custom through table for attaching the additional fields to the relationship.

Comment: @GorillaPatch  so I am getting rid of customer activity model and adding: customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer) to the Activity model?

Comment: @Atma look at this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany This describes exactly what you want. you want to attach extra data to the relationship. The advantage is that you can use standard django syntax for querying the relationship.

Comment: @Atma it is described here how to use the admin with M2M relationships with extra fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

Comment: @Atma, are you sure you need M2M? Can an Activity belong to multiple Customers?  If not, then you can just add "customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True)"

Comment: @GorillaPatch that is exactly what CustomerActivity is is a through table.  My question is how I create check boxes to make the relationship in a form.

Comment: @davko an activity CAN belong to multiple customers

Answer (score 0):

What makes this form different is the fact that you do not know the form fields upfront. Basically you want to generate a form based on database data. I coded the same thing once. The trick is that the Form object holds the individual fields in an instance variable called `fields` which is a sorted dictionary. The order in which you define the entries in the dict will be the order in which the form fields will appear in the form.

#### The code

```
#coding: utf-8

from django import forms
from models import Activity

class ActivitiesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, survey, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivitiesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_fields()

    def add_fields(self):
        # generate a queryset of the activities to show
        # could be sorted if a special order is needed
        activities = Activities.objects.all()
        if not activities:
            return
        
        for a in activities:
            # required false is important to allow the field NOT to be checked
            self.fields[a.id] = forms.BooleanField(label=a.name, required=False)
```

#### What it does

When a form is created it fetches all the activities from the database and adds a `BooleanField` for each activity to the form. The field name of this field will be the primary key of the activity and the label of the checkbox the activity's name. The order of how the checkboxes appear in the form will be the order of the primary key. To change that simply sort the queryset *activities* in the example to your needs.

When you now evaluate the form you get a list of numbers, which corresponds to the primary keys of the selected activities. From the list of the primary keys it is easy to retrieve the corresponding activity object from the database and add it to the m2m relationship on the customer object. Make sure to not use the standard django `add` function to add something to a m2m relationship as this would not work on m2m relationships with extra fields. Refer to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) for how it is done.